# C++ Convert UTF-8 character to binary form

Tags: c++, string, binary

I was trying to convert characters to binary string form like "A" to "01000001". To implement this, I used the following C++ code

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <bitset>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    
    string message = "A";
    string binaryString = "";

    for (char character : message) {
        binaryString += bitset<8>(character).to_string();
    }
    
    cout << binaryString << endl;
    
    return 0;
    
}
```

However, when I put a non-ASCII character(s) like "가"(`string message = "가";`), It shows wrong binary translations. For example, a non-ASCII character "가" should be translated to `1010110000000000`(`U+AC00`) but the suggested code shows `111010101011000010000000`, which is obviously different.

I want to know which points are wrong in the suggested code. Or, is there another way to conveniently convert from UTF-8 characters to binary forms?

Comment: Are you sure that `"가"` has only one unicode representation? How are your source file encoded?

Comment: @Jarod42 I'm unsure which encoding scheme is used for my source file because I'm just using `https://www.onlinegdb.com/`'s online C++ compiler.

Comment: Maybe `std::u8string message = u8"가";` could help in storing the UTF8 string.

Comment: What compiler and what are compiler flags? Encoding of string literals in final executable is controlled by compilation flags.

Comment: `가` is Unicode codepoint `U+AC00`. That is it's *id*. That is NOT it's encoded value.  It's encoding is NOT `0xAC00`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the character: **가**

- UTF-16 encoding is: `std::wstring message = L"\uAC00"` Notice that I have it declared as a wide string.  It could also be.... `std::u16string = u"\uAC00";`
- UTF-8 encoding is `std::string message = "\xEA\xB0\x80";` (3 bytes), which is that `111010101011000010000000` bit-string you mention above

In general it's not a good idea to have hardcoded non-ascii literals saved into source files. Otherwise, you rely on your IDE or text editor (and source code repository tools) to save it in the expected encoding. It only takes one person on your team with a different text editor to accidently save the original source file in a different encoding and not notice.

Answer (score 2):

Problem is encoding of string literals in final executable.
This is controlled by compiler.

I assume you are using MSVC, since (for comparability reasons) it has quirky behavior (other compilers assume utf-8):

[/execution-charset (Set execution character set) | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/execution-charset-set-execution-character-set?view=msvc-170)

> By default, Visual Studio detects a byte-order mark to determine if
> the source file is in an encoded Unicode format, for example, UTF-16
> or UTF-8. If no byte-order mark is found, **it assumes that the source
> file is encoded in the current user code page**, unless you used the
> **`/source-charset`** or **`/utf-8`** option to specify a character set name or code page. Visual Studio allows you to save your C++
> source code in any of several character encodings. For information
> about source and execution character sets, see [Character
> sets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/character-sets?view=msvc-170)
> in the language documentation.

So basically if there is no BOM in source file string literals will be encoded using your current system settings (code page). As result build result will depend on machine you build on.

Proper solution is:

- make sure what is encoding of source file (forcing UTF-8 is preferable).
- use same encoding when compiler reads source file
- set compiler to use `UTF-8` in final executable. `/execution-charset:utf-8`

If you enforce `UTF-8` encoring on source file then flag `/utf-8` will [set this encoding for source file and executable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/utf-8-set-source-and-executable-character-sets-to-utf-8?view=msvc-170).

Note also that, according to quote above, ensuring that source file has BOM solves the problem too.

---

For gcc utf-8 is assumed (and clang is was created to be compatible with gcc):

[Preprocessor Options (Using the GNU Compiler Collection (GCC))](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html#index-fexec-charset)

> `-fexec-charset=charset`
> [¶](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html#index-fexec-charset)
>
> Set the execution character set, used for string and character
> constants. The default is UTF-8. charset can be any encoding supported
> by the system’s `iconv` library routine.
>
> `-fwide-exec-charset=charset`
> [¶](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html#index-fwide-exec-charset)
>
> Set the wide execution character set, used for wide string and
> character constants. The default is one of UTF-32BE, UTF-32LE,
> UTF-16BE, or UTF-16LE, whichever corresponds to the width of `wchar_t`
> and the big-endian or little-endian byte order being used for code
> generation. As with -fexec-charset, charset can be any encoding
> supported by the system’s `iconv` library routine; however, you will
> have problems with encodings that do not fit exactly in `wchar_t`.
>
> `-finput-charset=charset`
> [¶](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html#index-finput-charset)
>
> Set the input character set, used for translation from the character
> set of the input file to the source character set used by GCC. If the
> locale does not specify, or GCC cannot get this information from the
> locale, the default is UTF-8. This can be overridden by either the
> locale or this command-line option. Currently the command-line option
> takes precedence if there’s a conflict. charset can be any encoding
> supported by the system’s `iconv` library routine.